# Find out which reference is clicked in a Visual Studio extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, project-reference

I'm developing a Visual Studio extension where I add elements to the right click (context) menu of the references in a project. This is done by defining a `Group` with the parent of `IDM_VS_CTXT_REFERENCE`.

I want to show-hide the menu elements depending on which reference was clicked, so I define my menu item as an `OleMenuCommand`:

```
if (commandService != null)
{
    var menuCommandID = new CommandID(CommandSet, CommandId);
    var menuItem = new OleMenuCommand(this.MenuItemCallback, menuCommandID);

    menuItem.BeforeQueryStatus += (sender, args) =>
    {
        var button = (OleMenuCommand)sender;
        button.Visible = this.CommandVisible();
    };

    commandService.AddCommand(menuItem);
}
```

I have trouble implementing the `CommandVisible` method. Let's say for the example's sake that I want to show the menu if the reference's name starts with `A`. How would I do that?

I feel like I'm trapped in interop hell stumbling blindly over arbitrary ids, guids and non-existant/incomprehensible documentation.

I have managed to dig out the project my reference is in as an `IVsProject` and some id for the reference, but calling `GetMkDocument` returns nothing (it works with files in the project but not with references).

How do I do this? Where can I find documentation on how to do this?

Comment: GetMkDocument  is only valid for actual documents, the references are just a visual aid and are not actually files. I'm running some tests to see if I can help you out.

Comment: Work came up but I took it as far as you got, the key is going to be using the IVsHierarchy methods using the itemid. I think you are on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got it. Once you have the IVsHierarchy and itemid of the selected item this line will get you the name you want in the out param.

```
hierarchy.GetProperty(itemid, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_Name, out name);
```

full code

```
object name;
uint  itemid = VSConstants.VSITEMID_NIL;
IVsMultiItemSelect multiItemSelect = null;
IntPtr hierarchyPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr selectionContainerPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
try
{
    var monitorSelection = Package.GetGlobalService( typeof( SVsShellMonitorSelection ) ) as IVsMonitorSelection;
    monitorSelection.GetCurrentSelection( out hierarchyPtr, out itemid, out multiItemSelect, out selectionContainerPtr );
    hierarchy = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown( hierarchyPtr ) as IVsHierarchy;    
    hierarchy.GetProperty(itemid, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_Name, out name);
}finally
{
     if (selectionContainerPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
         Marshal.Release( selectionContainerPtr );

      if (hierarchyPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
          Marshal.Release( hierarchyPtr );
}
```